# Why do jQuery Custom Widgets need namespaces?

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

Why does jQuery Widget Factory need a namespaced name for the widget, if the function is just going to be added to the jQuery object anyways? It seems like a useless exercise, since you'll be calling the widget from the jQuery object in practice.

Comment: IIRC the namespace is used for the triggered events and the pseudo selector used to select elements where the widget was instantiated.

Comment: Ok, I can grasp the namespaced events connection, but I'm still fuzzy on the second half of that. Can you elaborate or post a link in regards to the pseudo selector?

Comment: Every widget also comes with a selector so that you can select the widget elements of that particular widget. For example, in jQuery UI you can use `:ui-datepiker` and `:ui-accordion`.